# How do I see the password of the current user, c#

Tags: c#, credentials

I am developing a program in C# and I am having a problem with Windows credentials.

I need the program return me the user name and password.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   string[] user = Convert.ToString(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name).Split('\\');

   string userName = user[1];

   label1.Text = userName.ToString();
   label2.Text = passwd.ToString();

   //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, "1234"); //1234 = password
   //client.DownloadFile("http://**intranet**/servicosuporte/Documentos%20Partilhados/assistente_remoto.zip", @"C:\assistremoto.zip");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to see the user password? As admin you have your password to access the user machine. This question is smelling!

Comment: No, You can't get a user's password.

Comment: passwords are hashed, this is a one-way operation. It is designed to be not-reversible. If it is reversible, this is generally considered a security flaw.

Comment: @FeliceM I thought the same thing initially, but we probably should not assume malice of new users, right? Besides, if you look at the code, it is pretty clear that they just want to access network files.

Comment: @Gray, Thanks for your view. I have seen funny things in my corporate life. However, I agree with you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are unable to access a user's password in this way. Passwords are not reversible, and are hashed. This is a one-way operation.

If you want to use the user's existing credentials, you can use:

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials //for network
```

and

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials //for local
```